# Explain why converting objects to binary and comparing fails

Tags: c#

Using my code examples why don't the first two objects equal each other when converted to binary?

I know that I could write an override for the equals method and use that to check if two objects are alike. However I was experimenting with this method. Why do two identical objects convert to different binary values?

Given said class:

```
[Serializable]
public class HashingSample
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public HashingSample(int num)
    {
        Number = num;
    }

    public byte[] ToBinary()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = 
                new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And this code:

```
var s1 = new HashingSample(1).ToBinary();
var s1_2 = new HashingSample(1).ToBinary();
var s2 = new HashingSample(2).ToBinary();

var first2 = s1.Equals(s1_2);
```

Comment: arrays do not compare like that. you would need to iterate and compare each byte

Comment: Would a simpler way be to get the byte array as a string and compare strings

Comment: It would work but depending on the size it can easily run into memory issues

Comment: What about comparing at the stream level?

Answer (score 0):

They are equal. Their byte[] are the same length and have the same values.

The .Equals operator does not think so though.

This is probably because the actual instances of s1 and s1_2 are not the same (they are unique instances, so their hashcodes would not be the same.. an s1 is not truly an s1_2 despite having the same byte[] contents.)

Answer (score 0):

Equals does not do what you expect in the context of arrays - see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kathykam/2006/03/08/array-equals/ for more details.

Generally speaking, you should *assume* that Equals does a reference equality check (i.e. checks the two objects are the **exact** same object, as opposed to two different objects which happen to have the same properties / values in them) - unless the documentation explicitly tells you otherwise.

You could replace:

`var first2 = s1.Equals(s1_2);`

with:

`var first2 = StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(s1, s1_2);`

or

`var first2 = s1.SequenceEqual(s1_2);`

(or use the code from the link I provided)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using extensions

```
public static class HashingExtensions
{
    public static bool Compare(this object v1, object v2)
    {
        var w1 = v1.ToBinary(); var w2 = v2.ToBinary();
        if (w1.Count() == w2.Count())
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w1.Count(); x++)
            {
                if (w1[x] != w2[x])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Byte[] ToBinary(this object obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```